# Typhoon Injected parameter is nil in arm64

Tags: typhoon

I am working on a project where we are using Typhoon framework. This builds and run fine in simulator and arm7 architecture.
But when I start building it for arm64 architecture it start complaining about Typhoon property is `nil`. Finding actual issue in regards to `TyphoonInjectionByReference` which does not set.

Has anyone find this kind of issue, where it is going wrong.

`[initializer injectParameterWith:[self aMethod]];`

```
return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[aController class] 
    configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {

    [definition useInitializer:@selector(
      initWithNibName:dataProvider:headerViewController:pageTheme:refreshStrategy:) 
    parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {

    [initializer injectParameterWith:@"xyz"];
    [initializer injectParameterWith:[self aMethod]];
    [initializer injectParameterWith:nil];
    [initializer injectParameterWith:[[Assembler sharedInstance]
         definitionForAssemblyConfigurationKey:@"aTheme"]];
    [initializer injectParameterWith:[self aMethod]];
}];

definition.key = @"ControllerKey";
}];
```

Comment: Yes, The one injected with [self aMethod] is nil.                 This [initializer injectParameterWith:[[Assembler sharedInstance]
         definitionForAssemblyConfigurationKey:@"aTheme"]]; work fine

Comment: I am using version 'Typhoon', '2.0.6'

Comment: There were some arm64 issues around release of Typhoon 2.0, fixed in later versions. Though, from memory they were already fixed by 2.0.6, can you try upgrading first? Should me (99%) API compatible. . . . also, what is the implementation of `aMethod`?

Comment: aMethod is also creating TyphoonDefinition.

Comment: Pls suggest the easiest way to update with Latest version of Typhoon

Comment: Hi Jasper, I have updated with latest Typhoon version. Injected parameter nil issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues with arm64 around the release of a Typhoon 2.0. This issue can be resolved by updating to the latest 2.x version of Typhoon.